# Good resources for learning *modern* Cocoa for OS X (with Auto Layout, etc.) from scratch

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, autolayout

The most recent book about Cocoa that I was able to find is `Aaron Hillegass, Adam Preble - Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X - 2012`, however, it's outdated (based on Xcode 4.2; doesn't contain explanation of **Auto Layout**) and also it doesn't explain how to create UI completely in code. (Yes, Interface Builder is cool, but sometimes one needs to take control in his hands, to generate something at runtime, etc. — so this is an important topic, too)

Is there something which is more up-to-date, now, in 2014? (be it a book or an online resource — anything goes)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good question but it will likely be killed because it is not a specific programming questions.

Here are some pointers to get you started though:

- The book you mention is now actually still pretty relevant. I would most certainly go through it. Cocoa on the Mac has not evolved as quickly as Cocoa Touch has, so a lot of material from the past years is still very relevant.
- Documentation at the [Mac Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides) - Specifically, filter on the Guides and check out the most recent ones. You most definitely want to read about AutoLayout, Bindings, Modern Objective-C, and the Mac Techology Overview.
- [WWDC Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) - Apple has put these online freely, going back to 2010. There are some great sessions there. Check out all the "What's new in Cocoa" ones. And sessions with a title like "Introduction to ..."
- Ask lots of questions here :-)

I would like to see more pointers to more resources too. Specifically about 'modern app architecture'. I think that is a lot more clear on iOS than it is on OS X at this point.

Comment: I am not sure if going through those books would be relevant when 10.10 is out.